# TinyMCE : “forecolor” and “backcolor” buttons not showing up in toolbar

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Here is my tinymce script

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'div.tinymceinline',
  inline: true,  
  theme: 'modern',
  plugins: 'textcolor',
  toolbar1: 'forecolor backcolor',
});
```

Added plugin "textcolor" & "forecolor & backcolor" in toolbar options still its not showing up. 
Any Help?

[image]

Comment: Tried checking the docs?

Comment: `toolbar1` is correct?

Comment: @Akintunde: Yes, here is the doc. https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/

Comment: @Nishant: As per documentation.. yes "toolbar1" is correct. https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that works using your exact code:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/3bgaab/1

Does that work for you?  If so either something is cached in the browser or your configuration is not what you think it is.  Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!
Well it works for me as well outside my project directory.
The problem is when I implemented this in my project. All the plugins works except the "textcolor". Not sure whats going wrong. There's no error in console.